# Need to install java 6 but java 6 incompatible with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm

I downloaded Eclipse and Java 7, and when I try to open Eclipse I get this message "To open eclipse you need to install Java SE 6 runtime." When I download Java 6, it gives me an incompatible JVM error and says "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.7 or greater is required."

Comment: Go to the folder where eclipse is installed. Open `eclipse.ini` file and check the property `-vm` in there. If not set, then add it and add the path to the JVM (JRE) to use there, as shown here: [eclipse.ini Specifying the JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Comment: Maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314748/my-java-version-is-the-newest-version-but-my-jvm-is-still-1-5

Comment: Thanks! :) Eclipse.ini helped

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You might want to post this as an answer.

Comment: I don't know what version of eclipse you're using, but current ones run perfectly fine on java 8. so the message *"To open eclipse you need to install Java SE 6 runtime."* seems quite odd to me