# JVM version changing

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

**JVM Changing Problem**

```
I upgraded to java 8 but when I open eclipse it shows the following error:
```

> install JVM 1.8 or later

[image]

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/weMOq.png]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246910/eclipse-not-recognizing-jvm-1-8) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Java version is the newest version but my JVM is still 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314748/my-java-version-is-the-newest-version-but-my-jvm-is-still-1-5)